# Keyboard and Mouse stuck unexpectedly in Linux and restart automatically in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, keyboard, mouse

My keyboard and mouse freeze unexpectedly while working and I can't do anything. I'm forced to restart the computer to bring back the keyboard and mouse, and the problem is some of my files get lost. It's happening without any fixed intervals, maybe within half an hour, or after 4 or 5 hours etc.  My system is Ubuntu 10.04.

And when I check in Windows 7, it's restarting automatically.

Can anybody figure out the problem?

Comment: PS/2 or USB? Is screensaver set to random settings or OpenGL?  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze#Problem:__Freezes_occur_when_idle_and_screensaver_is_set_to_random_settings_or_OpenGL

Comment: Mouse is USB and screensaver set to random.

Comment: Switch to a 2D screensaver. At least my NVidia didn't like 3D screensavers.

Comment: But Keyboard and Mouse get stuck on time of working !!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a few symptoms.

1. Your windows is restarting.
2. Your mouse/keyboard is not working
3. Data loss

The data loss could be due to you are turning off the computer without shutting down. Linux really hates that. The mouse and keyboard getting stuck could be anything but combining that with a possible blue screen we are not probably looking at software but hardware. Specifically I suspect memory. The restarting could be your computer returning a blue screen of death. Try going into safe mode [F8] on boot and disabling restart on system failure.

1. Right click computer
2. Advanced system settings
3. Startup and recovery click on settings.
4. Uncheck automatically restart.

I would also run memtest86 to see if you have a possible memory issue.

Comment: I am working on Linux, I check in windows when these problems arises. But I couldn't figure out the problem yet.